# Installing new Scala SDK 3.x.x on IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I need to run Scala 3.x.x from IntelliJ. This is how I am trying to install it:

Click File > Project Structure...

[image]

Click on the "+" button (New Project Library):

[image]

Click "Scala SDK":

[image]

A new window pops-up showing a list of Scala SDK versions to choose from:

[image]

Scala 3.x.x is not listed for me. Even when I click the "Download..." button, I only see versions from 2.10.0 to 2.13.8:

[image]

How can I find Scala SDK 3.x.x?

**UPDATE 1:**

I see this question posted at [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-19125#:~:text=Go%20to%20project%20structure,of%20scala%20sdks%20after%20downloading](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-19125#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20project%20structure,of%20scala%20sdks%20after%20downloading), but no answer.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have IntelliJ IDEA Community 2020.2:

[image]

**UPDATE 3:**

I checked for updates:

[image]

I clicked "Update and Restart":

[image]

In the "IDE and Plugin Updates" window, I clicked "Update and Restart":

[image]

Something was being downloaded:

[image]

[image]

After restarting IntelliJ, updates took place:

[image]

Finally I have a newer version of IntelliJ IDEA installer:

[image]

I still only see versions 2.x.x available, even now that I have IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 (Community Edition) Build #IC-213.7172.25, built on March 15, 2022:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Works with latest IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Ultimate Edition) and should work as well with latest Community Edition.
[image: Scala 3 Global lib]

Answer (score 0):

Checking for updates will only download the latest 2021.x.x release.

You need to download and install the latest IntelliJ release instead from the website.

I would recommend to not uninstall your older version. You can still do that later after you got everything working with the new version.